# How to run script commands from variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I tried to run commands using pipes.

**Basic**:

```
single="ls -l"
$single
```

which works as expected

**Pipes**:

```
multi="ls -l | grep e"
$multi
ls: |: No such file or directory
ls: grep: No such file or directory
ls: e: No such file or directory
```

...no surprise

```
bash < $multi

$multi: ambiguous redirect
```

next try

```
bash $multi
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

Only

```
echo $multi > tmp.sh
bash tmp.sh
```

worked.

Is there a way to execute more complex commands without creating a script for execution?

Comment: See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're demonstrating the difference between the shell and the kernel.

"ls -l" is executable by the system execve() call. You can `man execve` for details, but that's probably too much detail for you.

"ls -l | grep e" needs shell interpretation to set up the pipe. Without using a shell, the '|' character is just passed into execve() as an argument to ls. This is why you see the "No such file or directory" errors.

Solution:

```
cmd="ls -l | grep e"
bash -c "$cmd"
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why "bash -c" prints the output in a single line? I would like to have the same output as entered manually at command line.

Comment: @stacker I don't think that's true. I get the same result as at the command line. Perhaps your grep is only returning a single line?

Comment: This happend because I forgot to enclose the variable in double quotes.

Comment: In my case I was trying to call a command that wasn't in the system path, I added its folder to my system path like shown here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/61349

Answer (score 0):

You need a `heredoc` to do this correctly. In answer to [POSIX compliant way to see if a function is defined in an sh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447555/posix-compliant-way-to-see-if-a-function-is-defined-in-an-sh-script/19885768#19885768), I detailed how to read a script into a variable, programmatically parse it for information and/or modify it as necessary, then execute it from another script or shell function. That's basically what you're trying to do, and the `heredoc` makes it possible because it provides a file descriptor:

```
% multi='ls -l | grep e'
% sh <<_EOF_
> ${multi}
> _EOF_
< desired output >
```

That would solve your simple example case. See my other answer for more.

-Mike

Answer (score -3):

when you want to run commands with pipes, just run it. Don't ever put the command into a variable and try to run it. Simply execute it

`ls -l |grep`

If you want to capture the output, use $()

`var=$(ls -l |grep .. )`

Comment: The commands come from a different server and should be excecuted on the target machine. Thus it can't be hard coded.