# POSIX way to find the path of foo without `which`?

Tags: posix, sh

I've encountered a machine that does not have `which`. How would you find the path to an executable `foo` without `which` in a POSIX compliant shell script, if `foo` might not even be present?

The code I have does the following:

- if `which` appears available according to `type which` exiting 0, then use it
- otherwise use `type foo` and depending on what `type` says it is (does the output contain any of the following: keyword, builtin, alias, hash, function), grab the path according to its likely position in the output.

The main problem with this, as @chepner and the man page point out, is `type` stdout is in an unspecified format.

My other problem is `foo` might not ever exit, so I can't just execute it to see what happens. I want to inspect it first so I need to know where it is.

I feel `find / -type f -name foo 2>/dev/null` would take too long. I suppose I could iterate over `$PATH` to find it directly. **Which approach is best? Iterating over `$PATH` or the approach in the two bullets above, or some other approach?**  I need the solution to be portable.

Comment: `type -P` *only* does a path search; if you don't a binary named `type` in your path, it will exit with status 1.

Comment: How come you made this a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a *good* answer. `type -P` isn't standard, so there is no guarantee that even if `type -P` is supported, it does what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Ah, you're right (of course). "The  standard  output  of  type  contains  information  about each operand in an unspecified format." Maybe I should change the question then.

Comment: `type stdout is in an unspecified format` While it is in unspecified format, there is only a limited count of existing shells that you are going to use - zsh, ash, dash, bash - and on all of them "it works" as in outputs just executable path. I once also [compiled&tested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447555/posix-compliant-way-to-see-if-a-function-is-defined-in-an-sh-script/69037385#69037385) original ksh from SVR4, and type there also outputted the executable path.

Answer (score 1):

```
command -v foo
```

will print the absolute path to `foo`, if it exists.

> command [-p][-v|-V] command_name
>
> -v
> Write a string to standard output that indicates the pathname or command that will be used by the shell, in the current shell execution environment [..], to invoke command_name, but do not invoke command_name.

Read more in the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) (functions, aliases, not found).